# How to create a link to open attached PDF in an specific page?

Tags: attachfile

I want to click on the link and open an attached PDF in a specific page.

Comment: This may be specific to Adobe Acrobat/Reader...

Comment: This works in Google Chrome `http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf#page=20` or even `http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf#subsection.4.2`

Comment: With hyperref I use \href[pdfnewwindow]{file.pdf\#target}{text} where file.pdf is either in the same directory or \hyperbaseurl and target is a \hypertarget name.

Comment: @HenriMenke in your answer, is the PDF file attached to the main PDF, or just linking between folders?

Comment: @JohnKormylo Could you give me a complete example?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating the document, you can either use `\hypertarget` to create the anchor name, or use \label and look in the aux file to find the corresponding anchor name.  If you have no control over the document, you can read the PDF file with an ASCII editor and search for the list of names (if any).

Target document (named test4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}% genertic text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\hypertarget{eq1}{\begin{equation}
x=a
\end{equation}}
\lipsum[6-10]
\end{document}
```

Main document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}% genertic text

\begin{document}
As shown in \href[pdfnewwindow]{test4.pdf\#eq1}{(1)} we know that $x=a$.

You can find this equation on \href[pdfnewwindow]{test4.pdf\#page.2}{page 2}.
\end{document}
```

The page.2 anchor was generated by `hyperref` automatically.  The is no guarantee it will work for all documents.

Comment: You can address absolute page numbers with `\href[pdfnewwindow,page=2]{test4.pdf}{page 2}` that doesn't depend on named destinations in the target pdf.

Comment: Follow-up question: [Expansion to create a link to open attached PDF in a specfic page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/636284/4301).