# Expansion to create a link to open attached PDF in a specfic page

Tags: pdf, links

This is a follow-up to the question linked in the *references* section with the difference that the page information is coming from a macro.  That is, instead of

```
\href[page=2]{foo.pdf}{page 2}
```

I would like to use

```
\def\PageNum{2}%
\def\HrefPageOption{page=\PageNum}%
\href[\HrefPageOption]{foo.pdf}{page \PageNum}
```

But, this results in

> Package keyval Error: page=2 undefined.

I have tried my usual expansion hacks, but have not been able to get this to work.
The expected output should have the complete last line:

[image]

### Notes:

- The [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301)  below runs as is.
  To get the error condition, the last line needs to be uncommented.
- As TeXShop uses MacOS pdfkit, the links created don't seem to work
  (matching behavior of MacOS Preview).
  However with Skim or Acrobat the links do work.

### References:

- [How to create a link to open attached PDF in an specific page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/320594/4301)

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{filecontents}{foo.tex}
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    
    \begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-5]
    \hypertarget{eq1}{\begin{equation}
    x=a
    \end{equation}}
    \lipsum[6-10]
    \end{document}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/320594/4301
As shown in \href[pdfnewwindow]{foo.pdf\#eq1}{(1)} we know that $x=a$.

You can find this equation on \href[pdfnewwindow]{foo.pdf\#page.2}{page 2}.

%% Ulrike Fischer's comment at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/320594/4301
You can also find this equation on \href[page=2]{foo.pdf}{page 2}.
\medskip\par

%% How do I get this to work?
\def\PageNum{2}%
\def\HrefPageOption{page=\PageNum}%
Alternatively, you can also find this equation on 
%\href[\HrefPageOption]{foo.pdf}{page \PageNum}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\expandafter\href\expandafter[\HrefPageOption`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Works great thanks. I had tried the second `\expandafter` _within_ the square brackets.