# Is it possible to create a hyperlink to a page that doesn't exist in the current document?

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, multiple-files

#### Is it possible to create a hyperlink to a page that doesn't exist in the current document?

The reason for asking, is that I have many documents on Overleaf, which are split in order to increase productivity by focusing on one specific document at a time, and in order to alleviate compile timeouts, among other vital reasons. I am unable to switch to a local TeX installation either.

I cannot simply merge the .tex source code into one large document and compile from there, as I would easily exceed the compile timeout limits on Overleaf for my account.

Is there a specific function or piece of code utilising hyperref that allows a clickable link to redirect the user to a specific page that is **not included** in the current document where the link will be created, but where that **page will be included once PDFs are merged** together using [PDFtk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/)?

In order to clarify, the process goes as follows:

1. Document 1 creates a clickable link to some certain page that is in Document 2, this link is **useless until all PDFs are merged**, only then the link **finds its correct destination**
2. Documents 1 through 2 are compiled separately and **merged** using PDFtk
3. Clicking on the link in Document 1 in the final merged document will take the user to the correct page that would have had been on Document 2 pre-merge

Take the following MWEs:

**Document 1:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum

% Create a link to page 10

\end{document}
```

**Document 2:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setcounter{page}{6}

\begin{document}

\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum

% Any code required here that would be necessary for a cross-PDF link?

\end{document}
```

These 2 PDFs would be merged together using PDFtk.

Some piece of code that does not work for this specific scenario is `\hyperlink{page.10}{On page 10...}`, I'm assuming this is due to the fact that a 10th page does not exist in Document 1, where there are only 5 available pages to create a hyperlink to.

*The goal is to create a clickable link on page 1 that would take the user to page 10 after both documents have been merged.*

Comment: If anything in this post is unclear, I would be more than happy to remedy it either by editing or providing an additional comment to clarify certain aspects. I recognise this is a very unlikely scenario for anyone to find themselves in, much less require an answer for. Cheers in advance to anyone who attempts to take a stab at this question.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320468/how-to-create-a-link-to-open-attached-pdf-in-an-specific-page although I have no idea how PDFtk  will affect them.

Comment: You can't create a link to a not existing page in the same document as you don't know the object number, but as John wrote you can create a link to an external document with `\href[page=20]{external.pdf}{on page 20}` it is then up to the merge application if it can handle it.

Comment: @JohnKormylo and @UlrikeFischer, thank you both for providing the solution to this problem. It seems that `\href[page=20]{external.pdf}{on page 20}` ended up working when merged using PDFtk. Since there isn't an "answer" on this post, I'm unsure of how to either close this question, or select a comment as an answer. I have upvoted both of your comments to show my gratitude. If there is anything I can do to close this question, please do advise.